# Two bars with rounded arrows overlapping each other in CSS

Tags: css, sass

I would like to have two bars with one bar having the rounded arrow at the end and the second one at the start. I have an example, but I just can't get the arrows rounded like on the image.

Image of how I want it to look:

[image: Desired output]

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/neco93/pen/gOwowmK).

```
.pointer-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 66px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  color: white;
  .left {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: #0D7FC2;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  .left:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: -44px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 45px solid #0D7FC2;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
  }
  .right {
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    background: #CCE5F3;
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #0D7FC2;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
  .right:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 45px solid white;
    border-top: 18px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 18px solid transparent;
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me with how I could do this?

Comment: Maybe this pen can help you; https://codepen.io/Sfate/pen/ngqfl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider clip-path to create the arrow shape and then apply a [gooey filter](https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/) to create the rounded effect (update `stdDeviation` to control the radius):

```css
.pointer-container {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  filter: url('#goo');
}
.pointer-container * {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}

.left {
  background: #0D7FC2;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 30px) 0,100% 50%,calc(100% - 30px) 100%,0 100%);
  margin-right:-5px;
}


.right {
  background: #CCE5F3;
  color: #0D7FC2;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,100% 100%, 0 100%,30px 50%);
  margin-left:-5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="pointer-container">
  <div class="left">a</div>
  <div class="right">b</div>
</div>


<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

You can add a variable to control the arrow:

```css
.pointer-container {
  --a: 30px;
  height: 50px;
  margin:15px 0;
  display: flex;
  color: white;
  filter: url('#goo');
}

.pointer-container * {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.left {
  background: #0D7FC2;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, calc(100% - var(--a)) 0, 100% 50%, calc(100% - var(--a)) 100%, 0 100%);
  margin-right: calc(-1*var(--a)/4);
}

.right {
  background: #CCE5F3;
  color: #0D7FC2;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, var(--a) 50%);
  margin-left: calc(-1*var(--a)/4);
}
```

```html
<div class="pointer-container">
  <div class="left">a</div>
  <div class="right">b</div>
</div>

<div class="pointer-container" style="--a:40px;">
  <div class="left">a</div>
  <div class="right">b</div>
</div>

<div class="pointer-container" style="--a:15px;">
  <div class="left">a</div>
  <div class="right">b</div>
</div>

<div class="pointer-container" style="--a:60px;">
  <div class="left">a</div>
  <div class="right">b</div>
</div>


<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="3" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok so this helped me very much! how could i change the border radius on the left of the first bar and the right on the second bar with with this gooey effect ?

Comment: @NemanjaVidačković it's the stDeviation that control all the radius at the same time. If you want to control each one differently I would need a different code

Comment: what other options do i have if i want to control each one differently? thank you